# Proposal for Improvement of Voting Display

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

I sometimes stumble upon questions (or answers) which happen to divide the audience greatly.  They get lots of up and lots of downvotes which then act more like a poll of ayes and nays.  In the end, the absolute difference isn't very helpful anymore without knowing how many contributors gave their vote; actually, they can give a rudely false impression:

[image]

This looks like a crappy question (or answer, this observation applies to both) because `-6` often appears shortly before the question gets deleted or marked as duplicate or similar.

Upon clicking the number, one can see the much more elaborate and meaningful numbers for up and downvotes:

[image]

Suddenly the question does not look *crappy* anymore but *controversial* or *disputed*.  Unfortunately this display appears only *after* one clicked the number, so many users are mislead by the initial display.

To improve this situation I propose to change the way the votes are *initially* displayed for Q/A which have ① more than ten upvotes and ② more than ten downvotes and ③ no quota below 15% for aye or nay.  Such a Q/A is proposedly to be regarded as "disputed" and disputed Q/A shall be displayed by giving a *percentage of approval* instead of an absolute difference:

[image]

Clicking on that number shall of course still give the double-number display for up and downvotes.  The color of the percentage number can be *between* green and red to indicate the tendency of the votes.

Comment: I think we should show up- and downvotes separately from the start, for everyone. Seems more intuitive than a percentage

Comment: upvotes and downvotes are more appealing than percentage

Comment: Please be careful.  I only intend to replace the `-6` by the `40%`.  The up/downvote display is not to be changed.

Comment: @Pekka, IIRC that would cripple the perfs, that's why it's not already done.

Comment: What are perfs?

Comment: @Alfe, performance.

Comment: Displaying two numbers shall take more performance than computing their difference and displaying just one value?  I don't think so. — I think this is no performance issue.  Computing the percentage also will not change anything the user can feel or can be measured on the server.

Comment: @Alfe, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/164403

Comment: May be a better proposal instead of the percentage,  would be showing a small number indicating the total number of votes below the voting score.

Comment: *This looks like a crappy question (or answer...)* But only because you blurred out the content. If a bunch of people are up (or down) voting despite the fact that a bun of other people are down (or up) voting, then that implies most people are voting based on content, not whatever the score happens to be when they vote.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, you refer to a post more than six years old?  Are you aware that such an information might be outdated?  After all server infrastructures improve and change.

Comment: @BSMP, Of course the indicator of the votes is there to give an impression of the popularity and the tendency of the public opinion on that post (no matter what I blurred).  A display of `-1` for a post with `+312/-313` is misleading.  A display of `+3` for `+643/-640` of course as well.  A display of `50%` or `51%` would reflect much better what people think about such a post.

Comment: @BSMP And I never implied or even mentioned that people could vote based on the current vote (what a strange idea you follow there).  I only indicated it _looked_ like a crappy post.  That could, e. g., lead to someone _ignore_ that post, despite the fact that this post might be very interesting because of it being so controversial.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I think that this behavior is intended. SO wants low rep users to see conclusive scores. Voters attempt to decide the score of the post.

Comment: @user193661 Right!  And I think it would be *more* conclusive (and less misleading) to use the percentage in case of highly controversial voting patterns.

Comment: *I never implied or even mentioned that people could vote based on the current vote* - All your question says is that controversial questions look like crappy questions based solely on score. If you don't want people to assume you're making the same complaint as previous meta questions where people argue that users are voting based on score, then your question needs to be more specific about what the actual problem is.

Comment: @user sure it's intended - but it's wrong and pointless. It's not a good thing to make a point-based privilege out of.

Comment: dunno... i think i'd rather see that a post has been upvoted 1000 times than see that it is 99% positive. A bit of the message gets lost when you move to a percentage on older popular posts. but, at the same time, that would make controversial popular posts show as less than 99% at least.

Comment: Percentage could be just as misleading: +1/-1 = 50%, but so does +150/-150. I think @πάνταῥεῖ had the right idea of showing total along with the score. Math will get you the rest of the way, if you are interested in the exact percent.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan THX for backing up :-)!

Comment: To support @FrédéricHamidi a more recent post from [Oded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269356/158100) on the vote split numbers.

Comment: @KevinB Of course.  A 99% chance isn't controversial.  That's why my post proposes a margin of 15%, so that only stuff between 15% and 85% is supposed to be displayed as percentage.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I proposed a lower limit of 10 upvotes and 10 downvotes, so +1/-1 would never be displayed as 50%.  If you feel that +20/-20 is substantially different from +200/-200 then we can increase this lower limit.  But at least *I* feel that for a +658/-483 voting I have about the same feelings as about a +2434/-1787 voting (which both reflect 57%), but only after I computed that percentage myself.  I propose to let SO do that for us.

Comment: @rene Okay, so it still is designed the way it is.  But I'm still sure that this is not actually *needed* to be this way.  And it could be changed of course.  Let's put it this way:  This question here is about whether displaying percentages under some circumstances makes sense.  In case we find this useful, I'm sure the system can be changed to enable this.  Current technical limitations should not dictate the design.

Answer (score 6):

> *"They get lots of up and lots of downvotes which then act more like a poll of ayes and nays. In the end, the absolute difference isn't very helpful anymore without knowing **how many contributors gave their vote**;"*

Why not simply showing a total number of votes as a small number indicator below the votes score then?

Showing percentage doesn't seem to be clearer for me, but just confusing and irritating.

Also you should take in account, that lower rep users aren't allowed to see the vote counts split for good reasons.
As mentioned in comments, votes should be given for judging the actual contents of a post, but not for the common senses tendency. That's why this view is not disclosed for non trusted users.

Comment: Actually I didn't know that one needs a specific rep to see the split.  What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: I always assumed it was due to the performance concerns. Putting a reputation requirement on it quickly reduces the number of people using it.

Comment: @Alfe I think it's because we encourage judging for contents rather trends seen as mentioned, and lower rep (untrusted users) should not take these trends into account. Though higher rep users might use that information, to judge that question should be closed or deleted.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the info.  Again, current technical concerns should not dictate the design.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, well, I think displaying a score of +2 for a +34/-32 voting is *not* encouraging anything.  If SO really aims for the goal of encouraging to ignore the votes, it does a rather bad job by cloaking them using this strange mechanism of just displaying the "score".  No, I rather think that is just a first implementation which just never got improved.